# Read data from mysql in spark-shell

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, integration

First i built sbt scala application to read data from mysql table in apache spark using this line of code.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("Fuzzy Match Analysis").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","file:///tmp/spark-warehouse").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
var df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306")
    .option("dbtable","(select * from engine.ecl limit 1) as onerow")
    .option("user", "root")
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    .option("password", "root")
    .load()
```

Now i am trying to read data from mysql table in spark shell using same method

```
scala> var df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306").option("user","root").option("password","root").option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","(select * from engine.ecl limit 1) as onerow")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@22e253c7
```

But when i try to see whats in the row using df.show() method it gives me following error.

```
scala> df.show()
<console>:26: error: value show is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader
       df.show()
```

I have tried resolving dependencies by adding these lines in

## \spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\conf\spark-defaults.conf.template

spark.driver.extraClassPath = C:/Program Files/MySQL/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath = C:/Program Files/MySQL/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar

Comment: thanks sir,however there are 2 more things i should mention here
1.  I added 
spark.driver.extraClassPath = C:/Program Files/MySQL/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar spark.executor.extraClassPath = C:/Program Files/MySQL/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar

spark-defauls.conf.template file but i also need to rename this file as spark-defauls.conf

And i also need to create new instance of  class using this line

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see (and also indicated by the *error message*), the `var df` in your`spark-shell` refers to a `DataFrameReader` and not a `DataFrame` because you haven't invoked the `load()` method of `DataFrameReader`.

> df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@22e253c7

---

As a good practise, always make sure to **specify types** (even though `Scala` *automatically infers* it) in order to avoid *gotchas* like this.

Answer (score 2):

To start mysql integration apache spark we need to follow these steps

1. To work with **MySQL** server in **Apache Spark** we need Connector/J for MySQL.
   Download [mysql-connector-java-5.1.36](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36), then add
   the class path to the conf/spark-defaults.conf

   > spark.driver.extraClassPath = C:/ProgramFiles/MySQL/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar
   >   spark.executor.extraClassPath = C:/ProgramFiles/MySQL/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar
2. You need to create a new instance of jdbc driver using this call

   > Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance
3. Using following [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) you can call mysql query in spark-shell.

   > val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("url" -> 
   >   "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/engine?user=root&password=root","dbtable"
   >       -> "engine.ecl","fetchSize" -> "10")).load()

or

1. > var df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url","jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306").option("user","root").option("password","root").option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","(select * from engine.ecl limit 1) as onerow").load()